# How to add multiline Text to a ListBox item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, listbox

I have a little problem and can't find a solution.
I would like to put a text at the end of a `ListBox` item and I have no idea how...

```
TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(paths[i]);
listBox1.Items.Add("0" + i + ". " + f.Tag.Title +"\n" + string.Join(", ", f.Tag.Performers) + " - " + "\r" + f.Tag.Album + "                                               "  + f.Properties.Duration.TotalMinutes.ToString());
```

I've already tried it but unfortunately it doesn't work that way. Maybe someone knows how you can always put the text at the end, with a code?

[image: I want the text of all items to match]
I want the text of all items to match each other
[image: And I can't find a solution how to put the text at the end and how the text can match each other]
And I can't find a solution how to put the text at the end and how the text can match each other

Comment: You need to do this without \n and \r.  Google "c# multiline listbox" if that is not practical.

Comment: Eihter right align by adding `TextFormatFlags.Right` to the flags or work with tabs.

Answer (score 10):

To add multiline text to a ListBox Control, you need to measure and draw the text yourself.

Set the [ListBox.DrawMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawmode) to [DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.drawmode), then override  [OnMeasureItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.onmeasureitem) and [OnDrawItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.ondrawitem).

→ `OnMeasureItem` is called before an Item is drawn, to allow to define the Item Size, setting the [MeasureItemEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.measureitemeventargs) **`e.ItemWidth`** and **`e.ItemHeight`** properties (you have to verify that the ListBox contains Items before trying to measure one).

→ When `OnDrawItem` is called, the **`e.Bounds`** property of its [DrawItemEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.drawitemeventargs) will be set to the measure specified in `OnMeasureItem`.

To measure the Text, you can use both the [TextRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer) class [MeasureText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext) method or [Graphics.MeasureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring). The former is preferred, since we're going to use the `TextRenderer` class to draw the Items' text: `TextRenderer.DrawText` is more *predictable* than [Graphics.DrawString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring) in this context and it renders the text *naturally* (as the ListBox - or ListView - does).

The `TextRenderer`'s [TextFormatFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textformatflags) are used to fine-tune the rendering behavior.  I've added `TextFormatFlags.ExpandTabs` to the flags, so you can also add Tabs (**`"\t"`**) to the Text when needed. See the visual example.
**`"\n"`** can be used to generate line feeds.

In the sample code, I'm adding `8` pixels to the measured height of the Items, since a line separator is also drawn to better define the limits of an Item (otherwise, when a Item spans more than one line, it may be difficult to understand where its text starts and ends).

▶ Important: the maximum **`Item.Height`** is **`255`** pixels. Beyond this measure, the Item's text may not be rendered or be rendered partially (but it usually just *disappears*). There's a Min/Max check on the item height in the sample code.

This is how it works:

[image: ListBox OwnerDrawn Multiline]

> I suggest to use a class object, if you haven't, to store your Items
> and describe them. Then use a `List<class>` as the
> `ListBox.DataSource`. This way, you can better define how each part
> should be rendered. Some parts may use a Bold Font or a different
> Color.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class ListBoxMultiline : ListBox
{
    TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.WordBreak |
                            TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping |
                            TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding |
                            TextFormatFlags.ExpandTabs |
                            TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;

    public ListBoxMultiline() { this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable; }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Items.Count == 0) return;
        if (e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Focus) || e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected)) {
            using (var selectionBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Orange)) {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(selectionBrush, e.Bounds);
            }
        }
        else {
            e.DrawBackground();
        }
        
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, GetItemText(Items[e.Index]), Font, e.Bounds, ForeColor, flags);

        if (e.Index != Items.Count - 1) {
            Point lineOffsetStart = new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Bottom - 1);
            Point lineOffsetEnd = new Point(e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom - 1);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LightGray, lineOffsetStart, lineOffsetEnd);
        }
        base.OnDrawItem(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMeasureItem(MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Items.Count == 0) return;
        var size = GetItemSize(e.Graphics, GetItemText(Items[e.Index]));
        e.ItemWidth = size.Width;
        e.ItemHeight = size.Height;
        base.OnMeasureItem(e);
    }

    private Size GetItemSize(Graphics g, string itemText)
    {
        var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, itemText, Font, ClientSize, flags);
        size.Height = Math.Max(Math.Min(size.Height, 247), Font.Height + 8) + 8;
        return size;
    }
}
```

Comment: The listbox looks really good and would really help me but when I try to create the class I get an error in the code System.ValueTuple´2 
is not defined or imported

Comment: What C# version do you use? The Named ValueTuple here requires C# 7.0+. You should also have a notification for `public ListBoxMultiline() => this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;`, since this form also is available from C# 7.0+. You can of course get rid of the Tuple and use two Point variables or a array of two Point elements. If you don't know how to edit the code, I'll make a note about it.

Comment: Just take the line offset start and end apart. We don't need tuples here: `Point lineOffsetStart = new Point(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Bottom - 1);
Point lineOffsetEnd = new Point(e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom - 1);
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LightGray, lineOffsetStart, lineOffsetEnd);` and the constructor `public ListBoxMultiline() { r this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable; }`

Comment: All right, made the edit. As @Olivier Jacot-Descombes noted, a named tuple is not really needed, I just like it :) Also changed the expression body constructor to the *normal* form.

Comment: @Jimi The Class is working now but when i try to import the listbox to my Project comes annother error. **InvalidArgument = Value with the word 0 is invalid parameter name for index: index** Line 20

Comment: Yep, the first line in `protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)` didn't make the cut (and I wrote about it in the notes :). Add that line: `if (Items.Count == 0) return;` and it'll be ok.

Comment: @Jimi How can i change the Brushes & Pens color to a RGB color?

Comment: See the edit, in OnDrawItem, the new SolidBrush (declared with a `using` statement since SolidBrush is a disposable object). You can of course use `Color.FromArgb()` instead of `Color.Orange`

Comment: @Jimi Very Cool thank you very much :)
One last question, how can I make the second line smaller? And could i use the \t to display the text behind it on the right side of the listbox? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: If you want to draw lines of different height, you can specify a different Font with a specific Font.Size (you need to create a new Font to set the Size), measure the string using this Font.Size and when you draw the Text, create a new Font object with the Size you like. To align to the right, modify the `TextFormatFlags`, e.g., `var rightFlags = flags | TextFormatFlags.Right;` and pass `rightFlags` to `TextRenderer.DrawText()`. That's why a suggested to use a class object to describe the ListBox Items, so you can have different settings for each item. Make a new question if you don't know how

Comment: @Jimi it does not work :/ but no matter I thank you that you put in so much effort  in this. maybe I will find a solution soon.

Comment: If there's something that you cannot get to work, take some time to test the objects described here, you'll get it right. If you're trying to left and right-align different parts of text in the same line, you cannot use flags, since there's no flag for that. You need to use hard-tabs. See the [ListBox.UseCustomTabOffsets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.usecustomtaboffsets), activated with [ListBox.UseTabStops](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.usetabstops). Not easy to do correctly if you haven't done it before.

Comment: any example project code ?