# How to show custom drawn lines in combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am looking for a way to draw multiple custom lines in my checkbox. I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ComboBox1.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
    ComboBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
    ComboBox1.DropDownWidth = 100
    ComboBox1.TabIndex = 0
    ComboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("test1")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("test2")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("test3")

    AddHandler ComboBox1.DrawItem, AddressOf ComboBox1_DrawItem

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs)

    e.DrawBackground()

    Dim black_pen As System.Drawing.Pen = New System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 2)
    black_pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.DashDotDot
    black_pen.Width = 2

    Dim point1 As System.Drawing.Point = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
    Dim point2 As System.Drawing.Point = New System.Drawing.Point(90, 10)

    e.Graphics.DrawLine(black_pen, point1, point2)

End Sub
```

I am looking for a way to show three different styled lines in my checkbox, which would be selected by the user. My current result is that I can only see one line so far (it's drawn on the top one combobox item) and other combobox items are empty. I see no values there.

How can I add additional lines/drawn graphics into my checkbox and make them "selectable"?

Comment: You're drawing all lines in the same *spot*. See here, for example: [How to add multiline Text to a ListBox item?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60589434/7444103). -- Btw, that's not the way to declare a Pen object. Declare it with a `Using` statement, it's a disposable object.

Comment: The `e` parameter provides the `Bounds` of the item being drawn so you need to use it to specify where to draw. If you want to draw on an item, draw within the bounds of that item.