# ListBox Change a Specific Item ForeColor

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, custom-controls

I'm struggling in creating customized functionality for a listbox.
I need my ListBox to change the Forecolor of a specific ("marked") item.
Not to be confused with Selected Item.

The Functionality Required:
Let's say the ListBox Collection Contains Several File Names.
When I double click an Item; that item index and object are stored into two variables (index and object).
These variables would then be used to set the Item ForeColor (when Listbox Item is Unselected).
Remaining Items and Item Rectangle should be drawn with default properties
(in this case they have their own color properties to allow further customization).

My problems:

- Not Painting upon Load
- String is Drawn with "Weird Characters"
- When Selecting an Item; I'm drawing the "Marked" Item.

I'm really confused. MSDN documentation is not very clear how to achieve this; nor how & when the DrawItem Event Occurs.

I've been messing with several alternatives; however deleted everything and got back to the current code attempting to understand the logic and behaviour.

**1st Attempt code (Original Question Code):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Custom_Controls.Controls
{
    internal class MyPlaylist : ListBox
    {
        public MyPlaylist()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);

            // Enable ListBox Customized Design
            DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
            //SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
        }

        #region <Custom Properties>
        private int markedIndex = -1;
        public int MarkedIndex
        {
            get { return markedIndex; }
            set { markedIndex = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        private object markedItem = string.Empty;
        public object MarkedItem
        {
            get { return markedItem; }
            set
            {
                markedItem = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private Color markedItemForeColor = Color.Red;
        public Color MarkedItemForeColor
        {
            get { return markedItemForeColor; }
            set { markedItemForeColor = value; Invalidate(); }
        }


        private Color markedItemBackColor = Color.DimGray;
        public Color MarkedItemBackColor
        {
            get { return markedItemBackColor; }
            set { markedItemBackColor = value; Invalidate(); }
        }


        private Color selectionBackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
        public Color SelectionBackColor
        {
            get { return selectionBackColor; }
            set { selectionBackColor = value; Invalidate(); }
        }


        private Color selectionForeColor = Color.White;
        public Color SelectionForeColor
        {
            get { return selectionForeColor; }
            set { selectionForeColor = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        #endregion


        
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e) // When Selected?
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();

        //// Improve Graphic Quality and Pixel Precision
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        
        using (var defaultForeBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
        using (var markForeBrush = new SolidBrush(markedItemForeColor))
        {
            // Iterate over all the items
            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = Items[i];

                // Draw "Marked" Item
                if (i == markedIndex)
                { 
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(Items[markedIndex].ToString(), e.Font, markForeBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault); 
                }

                // Draw Remaining Items
                else
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(item.ToString(), e.Font, markForeBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
                }

                // Draw Selection Rectangle
                // ...
            }
        }
    }        



        #region <Overriden Events>
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

        protected override void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnDoubleClick(e);

            SetMarkedItem();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e);

            SetMarkedItem();
        }


        #region <Methods>
        private void SetMarkedItem()
        {
            markedIndex = SelectedIndex;
            markedItem = SelectedItem;
        } 
        #endregion
    }
}
```

---

**My 2nd Attempt using Jimi's Help (Current Code)**

**Changes:**

- I've Commented the Pinvoke LB_ Enums and WndProc as I was not able to make it work.
- In order to keep simplicity: I removed the ternary operators (however I loved the way Jimi's code would alternate the colors with them).
- SetMarker() was reverted to previous version. The Marked Item was never Drawn that way.
- Custom Properties were not providing their value to the Brushes; therefore they were temporarily removed.

**Current Issues:**
WndProc definitly needs to be reimplemented to clear the Drawing (Marked Item); and perhaps to Redraw the Control so it Updates the Marker ASAP.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Custom_Controls.Controls
{
    internal class MyPlaylist : ListBox
    {
        #region <Constructor>
        public MyPlaylist()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);

            DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;

            BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 25, 25, 25);
            ForeColor = Color.White;
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        }
        #endregion


        #region <Fields>
        //private const int LB_RESETCONTENT = 0x0184;
        //private const int LB_DELETESTRING = 0x0182;

        //TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping | TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;
        #endregion


        #region <Custom Properties>
        // Tip: Always Verify that the new Values are Different from the Old Ones

        private int markedIndex = -1;
        public int MarkedIndex
        {
            get { return markedIndex; }
            set
            {
                if (value != markedIndex)
                {
                    markedIndex = value;
                    Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        // Read-only: just return the marked Item, set it using the Index only
        public object MarkedItem
        {
            get { return Items[markedIndex]; }
        }
        #endregion


        #region <Overriden Events>
        protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Items.Count == 0) return;

            // Draw Selection:
            if (e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Focus) || e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected))
            {
                using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 52, 52, 52)))
                {
                    // Background Rectangle
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);

                    // Item Text : Marked Item
                    if (e.Index == markedIndex)
                    {
                        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, GetItemText(Items[e.Index]), Font, e.Bounds, Color.Red, flags);
                    }
                    
                    // Other Items (Except Marked)
                    else
                    {
                        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, GetItemText(Items[e.Index]), Font, e.Bounds, Color.White, flags);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Draw Unselected:
            else
            {
                using (var brush = new SolidBrush(BackColor))
                using (var markedBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Khaki))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
                    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, GetItemText(Items[e.Index]), Font, e.Bounds, Color.White, flags);
                }

                // Draw (Unselected) Marked Item
                if (markedIndex > -1 && e.Index == markedIndex)
                {
                    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, GetItemText(Items[e.Index]), Font, e.Bounds, Color.Red, flags);
                }
            }

            e.DrawFocusRectangle();

            base.OnDrawItem(e);
        }

        // Set the Height of the Item (Width: only if needed).
        // This is the Standard Value (Modify as required)
        protected override void OnMeasureItem(MeasureItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Items.Count > 0)
            {
                e.ItemHeight = Font.Height + 4; // 4 = Text vs Item Rectangle Margin
            }

            base.OnMeasureItem(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }

        protected override void OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnDoubleClick(e);

            SetMarkedItem();
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e);

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                SetMarkedItem();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region <Methods>
        /// <summary>
        /// WndProc is Overridden in order to Intercept the LB_RESETCONTENT (sent when the ObjectCollection is cleared);<br/> 
        /// and the LB_DELETESTRING (sent when an Item is removed).
        /// This is done to reset the marked Item when the list is cleared or the marked Item is removed (otherwise an Item will remain marked when it shouldn't).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="m"></param>
        //protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        //{
        //    switch (m.Msg)
        //    {
        //        // List Cleared
        //        case LB_RESETCONTENT:
        //            markedIndex = -1;
        //            break;

        //        // Item Deleted
        //        case LB_DELETESTRING:
        //            if (markedIndex == m.WParam.ToInt32())
        //            {
        //            markedIndex = -1;
        //            }
        //            break;
        //    }
        //}

        private void SetMarkedItem()    // Current Block
        {
            markedIndex = SelectedIndex;
        }

        // Previous Code Line (By Jimmy; using Ternary Operator) <----------------------------------------
        //private void SetMarkedItem() => MarkedIndex = markedIndex == SelectedIndex ? -1 : SelectedIndex;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

---

**Helpful Related Content**

[ListBox : Pinvoke LB_(Enums)](https://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/LB_.html)

[How to add multiline Text to a ListBox item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60589434/7444103)

Comment: `OnDrawItem` is called for each Item, you don't loop the entire list of items each time -- Use the `DrawItemEventArgs` for the Index -- Your ListBox mode is `OwnerDrawVariable`, you're supposed to also override `OnMeasureItem` -- Remove `InterpolationMode`: there's no interpolation here. The same for `PixelOffsetMode`: you're not drawing a Bitmap -- Use `TextRenderer.DrawText()` instead of `Graphics.DrawString()` -- Other stuff is not correct,  see the example here: [How to add multiline Text to a ListBox item?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60589434/7444103)

Comment: How do you *unmark* an Item?

Comment: @Jimi: Thank you your advise. Will try as recommended.
Yes; that also occurred to me.. How do I undraw/Redraw? The Items seem to be Drawn over the the current one.
My experience tells me that this could be something according to e.Graphics<...>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample class contains the adjustments needed to make the List work as the standard ListBox, but with the *enhancements* described in the question.
See also the comments in code.

- [TextRenderer.DrawText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext) replaces `Graphics.DrawString()`: this will give a more *natural* aspect to the rendered list items. No need to use anti-aliasing.
- [OnMeasureItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.onmeasureitem) is also overridden, to provide a custom Height (optionally the Width - when strictly required) for the Items. It's set to `ListBox.Font.Height + 4` (pretty standard); modify as needed.
- `OnDrawItem()` is corrected to handle both the custom Selection colors and the marked Item's colors. Note that this method is called once per Item, so you don't have to loop the entire collection each time, just paint the current Item with correct colors.
- `SetMarkedItem()` is modified to toggle the state of a marked Item, in case you double-click it twice.
- `WndProc` is overridden to *intercept* `LB_RESETCONTENT` (sent when the `ObjectCollection` is cleared) and `LB_DELETESTRING` (sent when an Item is removed). This is done to reset the marked Item when the list is cleared or the marked Item is removed (otherwise an Item will remain marked when it shouldn't).
- When setting a Property value, always verify that the new value is not equal to the old one, before you call `Invalidate()` (or any other method - or a Property setter) for no reason.
- A few minor changes, see the code.

---

```
public class MyPlaylist : ListBox {

    private const int LB_DELETESTRING = 0x0182;
    private const int LB_RESETCONTENT = 0x0184;

    TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping |
                            TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding |
                            TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;

    public MyPlaylist()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg) {
            // List cleared
            case LB_RESETCONTENT:
                markedIndex = -1;
                break;
            // Item deleted
            case LB_DELETESTRING:
                if (markedIndex == m.WParam.ToInt32()) {
                    markedIndex = -1;
                }
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    private int markedIndex = -1;
    public int MarkedIndex {
        get => markedIndex;
        set {
            if (value != markedIndex) {
                markedIndex = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    // Read-only: just return the marked Item, set it using the Index only
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public object MarkedItem {
        get => Items[markedIndex];
    }

    // Always verify that the new value is different from the old one
    private Color markedItemForeColor = Color.Orange;
    public Color MarkedItemForeColor {
        get => markedItemForeColor;
        set { 
            if (value != markedItemForeColor) {
                markedItemForeColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private Color markedItemBackColor = Color.DimGray;
    public Color MarkedItemBackColor {
        get => markedItemBackColor;
        set { 
            if (value != markedItemBackColor) {
                markedItemBackColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private Color selectionBackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
    public Color SelectionBackColor {
        get => selectionBackColor;
        set { 
            if (value != selectionBackColor) {
                selectionBackColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private Color selectionForeColor = Color.White;
    public Color SelectionForeColor {
        get => selectionForeColor;
        set { 
            if (value != selectionForeColor) {
                selectionForeColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    // Use TextRenderer to draw the Items - no anti-aliasing needed
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Items.Count == 0) return;
        if (e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Focus) || e.State.HasFlag(DrawItemState.Selected)) {
            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(selectionBackColor)) {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
            }
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, GetItemText(Items[e.Index]), Font, e.Bounds, selectionForeColor, flags);
        }
        else {
            var color = markedIndex != -1 && markedIndex == e.Index ? markedItemBackColor : BackColor;
            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(color)) {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
            }
            var foreColor = markedIndex == e.Index ? markedItemForeColor : ForeColor;
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, GetItemText(Items[e.Index]), Font, e.Bounds, foreColor, flags);
        }
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        base.OnDrawItem(e);
    }

    // Set the Height (the Width only if needed) of the Item
    // This is the standard value, modify as required
    protected override void OnMeasureItem(MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Items.Count > 0) {
            e.ItemHeight = Font.Height + 4;
        }
        base.OnMeasureItem(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
            SetMarkedItem();
        }
        base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e);
    }

    private void SetMarkedItem() => MarkedIndex = markedIndex == SelectedIndex ? -1 : SelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: Lots of Interesting ways if doing things. At first I wasn't able to add the control with the new code. The WndProc is causing Error.
I temporarily removed it; and have been trying to figure out how the marked item would be set; but on double click: no visual change is seen. Changing the Color will set all items color. Will keep testing as it will bring me better understanding. Also: Thanks for pointing the OnMeasureITem and the link for multi-lined items; that is really interesting and opens new perspectives on a listbox purpose.

Comment: By the way:
LB_RESETCONTENT value should be 0x0184; correct?

Comment: @Jimmi: I did create a new class and copied the whole thing. It causes a win32 Error

Comment: Yep, something went wrong while pasting some stuff here. Also the call to `base.WndProc(ref m);` went missing somehow, that's why have an exception there. Fixed. It looks like the rest is all there -- Overwrite everything with the edited code.

Comment: Final Comment towards your help:
Outstanding Answer!